# I cant delete registry subkey

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I'm making an app for game, If you banned from the servers. You got 2 random numeric keys in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Windows\`

The button1(Delete the first subkey at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`)

but when i put the same code in button2 its find subkey in Software\windows but its give error while delete.

```
string[] dummy = new string[10];

foreach (string s in Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\Microsoft").GetSubKeyNames())
{
    RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\Microsoft" + "\\" + s);
    string Key = rk.ToString();
    string Key2 = Key.Replace("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\", "");
    bool Check = IsDigitsOnly(Key2);
    if (Check)
    {
        RegistryKey ecks = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\Microsoft" + "\\" + s);
        {
            string ecks2 = ecks.ToString();
            string ecksxd = ecks2.Replace("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\", "");
            string[] hello = GetRegistry2(ecksxd);
            Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey(Key2);
        }
    }
}
```

## PROJECT SOURCE

## [CLICK HERE TO SEE SOURCE](https://justpaste.it/4uyt3)

Comment: What exception are you exactly getting?

Comment: i got ArgumentExpection

Comment: you should expand the exception you are getting and read the message. it might help you diagnose your problem

Comment: It says The subkey tree can not be deleted because there is no subkey. but when i put the mouse on (KEY2) its show the true subkey

Comment: Which line do you get the exeption at? What is the exception message? Is there an InternalException? Do you build your application as x86 or x64 or AnyCPU? What are IsDigitsOnly and GetRegistry2? Waht is the value of Key2 variable at the moment you call DeleteSubKey?

Comment: It looks like your going to delete *any key* in `\Microsoft` that's numeric?  That seems like a very bad idea, its not a location to mess about with.  The error is likely because you just pass the key name to `Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey()` which has no idea of the related path.  Your also leaking all those disposable key variables.

Comment: Check the source please! i put now.

Comment: PROJECT SOURCE https://justpaste.it/4uyt3 can anyone help
??

Comment: help plz i need help

Comment: You're searching for a key in HKCU/Software/Microsoft and then try to delete a key with the same name in HKCU/ . Is this intentional?

Comment: the game create a subkey in HKCU/ name is like xxxxxxxxx (9 number) and create a subkey in HKCU/Software/Microsoft/ name is like xxxxx (5numbers) the button 1 delete the XXXXXXXXX file but the button2 cant delete xxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## DONE! I FOUND ERROR. THE PROBLEM IS GETTING WHILE TRY TO DELETE SUBKEY DIRECTLY!

I ADD THIS CODES

`RegistryKey hkcus = Registry.CurrentUser;
RegistryKey sware = hkcus.OpenSubKey(@"Software\\",true);
RegistryKey msoft = sware.OpenSubKey(@"Microsoft\\",true);
msoft.DeleteSubKey(Key2,true);`

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that you're trying to delete a key in HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Blah/CurrentVersion/MyCoolSubKey. When you do

```
string Key2 = Key.Replace("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\", "");
```

your Key2 (why it is capitalized btw?) becomes

```
Blah/CurrentVersion/MyCoolSubKey
```

Then you call

```
Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey(Key2);
```

Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey have no idea about where Key2 came from. It just does what you've said it to do: "delete subkey named **Blah/CurrentVersion/MyCoolSubKey** from HKCU"

Which is effectively an attempt to delete

```
HKCU/Blah/CurrentVersion/MyCoolSubKey
```

There is no wonder it can't find that subkey.

While I believe that your' whole idea about indiscriminately deleting random keys in the registry is totally flawed, talking about algorithm, you might improve it by throwing away all the unused code and keeping it simple, something like this:

```
foreach (string s in Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft").GetSubKeyNames())
{
    if (s.All(Char.IsDigit))
    {
        Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKey($"Software\\Microsoft\\{s}");
    }
}
```

Again, I strongly dislike the idea of meddling with registry in such a way.

Comment: What do you mean? when i press the button its create a subkey like (MyCoolSubKey) then delete the subkey at HKCU/Software/Microsoft/

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: I need create a example in the button2_click event?